# Mysql, PHP Laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have following tables on Production with the respective counts of records,

- **people** count=                '565367'
- **donors** count=               '556325'
- **telerec_recipients** count=   '115147'
- **person_addresses** count=     '563183'
- **person_emails** count=        '106958'
- **person_phones** count=        '676474'
- **person_sms** count=           '22275'

On the UI end I want to display some data by applying some **joins or left joins**, and at the end by grouping, ordering and paginating I'm generating a json response.

So for achieving this I tried 2 methods, one by **creating the view file** of the join queries and apply where, group by and order by clauses inside controller, and second by directly firing the laravel syntax of joins in my controller.

Because I have a **large data** in all the tables, The join query works good but when it comes to group by statement it takes much time to execute.

Help me out in order to optimize or faster this process.

My Example Query is:

```
SELECT people.id as person_id,donors.donor_id,telerec_recipients.id as telerec_recipient_id,people.first_name,people.last_name,people.birth_date,
person_addresses.address_id,person_emails.email_id,person_phones.phone_id,person_sms.sms_id 
FROM `people` 
inner join `donors` 
on `people`.`id` = `donors`.`person_id` 
left join `telerec_recipients` 
on `people`.`id` = `telerec_recipients`.`person_id` 
left join `person_addresses`
on `people`.`id` = `person_addresses`.`person_id` 
left join `person_emails` 
on `people`.`id` = `person_emails`.`person_id` 
left join `person_phones` 
on `people`.`id` = `person_phones`.`person_id` 
left join `person_sms` 
on `people`.`id` = `person_sms`.`person_id` 
GROUP BY `people`.`id`, `telerec_recipients`.`id` 
ORDER BY `last_name` ASC LIMIT 25 offset 0;
```

Result of the explain:

[image]

[Donors Table Indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFRRR.png)

Comment: Pls provide the result of the explain, until any proposed solution is a pure guesswork.

Comment: @Shadow, do I need to provide you the output of the above query?

Comment: No, the result of the explain.

Comment: @Shadow,
Here is my EXPLAIN result set,
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5fZSYyNho3zUlhnbVdkd1pDeDA

Comment: Can you pls copy it into the question itself? Cannot access gdrive from where I'm atm.

Comment: @Shadow,
See the link attached with the question.

Comment: Pls also include the index definitions of the 3 indexes on the donors table listed in the possible keys and key columns. Most likely MySQL's optimiser makes a wrong decision on which index to use.

Comment: @Shadow,
Please see the link Donors Table Indexes above attached with the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that MySQL uses the wrong index on the `donors` table, you need to instruct MySQL using `force index` [index hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) to use the `primary key` instead.

**Explanation**

From the output of the explain it is clear that sg really goes wrong with `donors` table, since you can see `using temporary, using filesort` in the extra column.

The `key` column tells you that MySQL uses a unique index on the `donors.donor_id` field. However, `donor_id` field is not used anywhere in the query for joining / grouping / filtering purposes. `donors.person_id` field is used in the join. Since the primary key of `donors` table is on the `person_id` field, myql should use that for the join. `force index` index hint tells MySQL that you firmly believe that a certain index should be used.

Note 1:
You have several duplicate indexes. Remove all duplicates, they are only slowing your system own.

Note 2:
I think you query is against the sql standards because you have fields in the select list that are neither in the group by list, nor are subject of an aggregate function such as `sum()`, nor are functionally dependent on the grouping fields. In MySQL under certain sql mode settings such queries are allowed to run, but they may not produce entirely the same output as you would like.

Comment: I modified the query that meets the best sql standards, still it gives me the same issue of delay.

Comment: Question remains the same, like how do i get rid of those using temporary, using filesort from donors index listed inside extra column.

Comment: I did give you an answer for that.